# Passing a JWT token and JSP page together to browser, Springboot

Tags: spring-boot

Newbie here, i'm trying to pass a jwt token on the response as well as a new jsp page to the browser, but can't seem to return both together due to the methods data type(It's either String for Passing JSP or ResponseEntity<> for passing the token). How should i proceed about this? is there an alternative way of doing this?

```
public String createAuthenticationToken(@RequestParam("userName") String username, @RequestParam("Password") 
String password, Model model) throws Exception {
    
    authenticate(username, password);
    
    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
```

/*This only works if methods type is ResponseEntity, but i need to pass this as well*/
return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));

```
    model.addAttribute("UserName",username);
    model.addAttribute("token",token);
    return "homepage";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I understand it, you are trying to validate the user's credentails as part of login and then showing the home page in case the credentials are valid. Also, return a jwt token.

If this is the case, you could consider returning the token in a secure cookie. Here is a simple example I made up to show how this can be done using a dummy user: https://github.com/nkumashi/springboot-webmvc-demo.

The crux of the project is this block of code in the UserController.java class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // extract user details and verify provided credentials
    // using a dummy user to keep things simple
    if(user.getFirstName().equals(dummyUser)) {
        // user login success
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token", "dummy-token");
        cookie.setMaxAge(COOKIE_EXPIRY_IN_SECONDS);
        cookie.setSecure(false);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        
        response.addCookie(cookie);
        model.addAttribute("User", user);
        // show the home page / user details
        return "showUser";
    } 
    // login failure
    model.addAttribute("message", "Invalid user!");
    return "error";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, could you please tell me how to handle this cookie from client side ones he gets it? I'm using JSP and springboot.

Comment: Hi Amal ! Well, the client does not have to explicitly do anything. The browser automatically adds the server side cookies next time the client makes a request to the same domain. 
Every cookie should have an expiry date. The browser automatically removes the cookie upon expiry. And, when the client makes the next request without a cookie, the request fails with a 401.
I think the client does not need to be aware of the JWT token. As long as the client attaches the secure cookie (containing the token), the requests are processed else rejected. If rejected, the client has to get a new token.

Comment: Thank you, i managed to implement it. You've been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is not clear. I see you have already added token into the model using `model.addAttribute("token", token)` but have you consumed it from `homepage` template ? Model acts like a key-value store for sharing information with view template and its the template's responsibility to extract relevant information and include them in the response sent back to the client.

On a side note, you also seem to be using `password` as a request parameter which is never recommended. Always use HTTP post body for such sensitive information.

Comment: Thank you for responding Nilesh, What i'm trying to do is pass a token on the http response, and return the page as well. Don't mind that i've used model to set the token on it. I just want to send the token and the page separately so i can display a "You are logined page" but also the token separately so the client can use it to validate itself later on. But if there's an alternative way to do this please recommend that too. I'm pretty new into this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public String createAuthenticationToken(@RequestParam("userName") String username, @RequestParam("Password") 
String password, Model model, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    
    authenticate(username, password);
    
    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    
    final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
    
    response.addHeader("token", token);
    model.addAttribute("UserName",username);
    model.addAttribute("token",token);
    return "homepage";
}
```

This is what i came up with, adding a header